# Can I add a view in list view with out using xml file

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, layout-inflater

I am learning android and I want to know if I can add a view with out using xml file as template for view
, any examples for help

Comment: Please add some more details. Your Question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use `.addView()`, if for example you have a ListView that you want to add a TextView to, you can just do:

```
ListView yourListView = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.yourListView);
TextView newTextView = new TextView(activity);
newTextView.setText("foobar");
yourListView.addView(newTextView);
```

`activity` should be `this` if you are in an Activity, or `requireActivity()` if you're in a Fragment.
You can set many other properties of this new TextView (or whatever View you are adding), just try typing `.set` after it, and look at the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add views to layout programmaticaly by using `addView()` method provided by the ViewGroup class.
First of all you should take a reference to your layout by using `findViewById<>()`.
Then you must create a view to add:

```
val listView = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.list_view)
        val view = Button(this)
        view.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        listView.addView(view)
```

Above I added a button lo my linear layout with list_view id.
The layout parameters are the correspondent width and height.